# Doubly linked list back pointer

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I have to implement this doubly linked list. The list needs a front pointer pointing to the first valid element and a back pointer pointing to the last valid element.

My problem with this code is with the last few lines when I have to implement T& back and define the end iterator.What I have currently is not working

```
#ifndef List_dllist_h
#define List_dllist_h
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
class DList
{
struct Node
{
    Node(const T& x,Node* y = 0):m_data(x),m_next(y),m_prev(y){}
    T m_data;
    Node* m_next;
    Node* m_prev;
};

Node* m_head;
Node* m_back;

public:

class iterator
{
    Node* m_rep;
public:
    friend class DList;

    inline iterator(Node* x=0):m_rep(x){}
    inline iterator(const iterator& x):m_rep(x.m_rep) {}
    inline iterator& operator=(const iterator& x)
    {
        m_rep=x.m_rep; return *this;
    }
    inline iterator& operator++()
    {
        m_rep = m_rep->m_next; return *this;
    }
    inline iterator operator++(int)
    {
        iterator tmp(*this); m_rep = m_rep->m_next; return tmp;
    }
    inline iterator& operator--()
    {
        m_rep= m_rep->m_prev; return *this;
    }
    inline iterator operator--(int)
    {
        iterator tmp(*this); m_rep= m_rep->m_prev; return tmp;
    }
    inline T& operator*() const { return m_rep->m_data; }
    inline Node* operator->() const { return m_rep; }
    inline bool operator==(const iterator& x) const
    {
        return m_rep == x.m_rep;
    }
    inline bool operator!=(const iterator& x) const
    {
        return m_rep != x.m_rep;
    }

   };


DList() : m_head(0), m_back(0) {}
~DList() { clear(); }


inline T& front() { return *begin(); }
inline const T& front() const { return *begin(); }


inline T& back() { return *--end(); }
inline const T& back() const { return *--end(); }

inline iterator begin() { return iterator(m_head); }
inline iterator end() { return iterator(m_back); }



};
#endif
```

Edit: added --operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with the `back()` iterator is a bit more complex than it seems at first. `back()` is closely related to `end()`, however your `end()` implementation is not going to work correctly, which I'll explain in a moment. Your iterator class is not really designed to represent the `end()` value very well, as it's currently written.

But let's pretend, for just one moment, that your `end()` iterator was nice and good. If that were the case, your `back()` could simply written as:

```
inline T& back() { return *--end(); }
```

That's the classical definition of `back()`. That's what it is. The `const` version is going to be analogous.

The fact that you do not have the `--` operator defined yet is not a big deal. That's a side issue, you can easily define it like the `++` operator, that you're already coded. Let's consider that part done. The major problem is your actual `end()` value:

```
inline iterator end() { return iterator(m_back +1); }
```

That's a major fail in several ways. `m_back` is a pointer to the last element in a doubly-linked list. `m_back` is going to be the next memory location after the last element. Which really is not very meaningful, and furthermore it is completely wrong for the following simple reason.

Additionally, when your list is empty, `m_back` is null, so `m_back+1` is undefined behavior! Oops. But, as you know, `end()` of an empty container must be a perfectly valid iterator.

Now, consider the situation where your `iterator` is referencing the last element in the doubly-linked list. In that situation, incrementing it with the `++` operator should give you the `end()` value. Because that's what it is. Now, stop and think for a moment. Is that's what's going to happen, after your `operator++()` finishes "incrementing" the iterator that's referencing the last element in your doubly-linked list? Of course not.

Also, keep in mind the fundamental axiom that your `end()` iterator's value should remain the same after a new node is `push_back`()ed to the end of your custom container. But when that happens in your code, you're going to have a completely new `m_back`. And `m_back+1` is now completely different. What happened to your prior "m_back+1"? It's suddenly morphed into something other than the `end()` value. In fact, it doesn't point to any part of the doubly-linked list at all. It points to the memory location that's after some existing element in the list.

So, the issue with your `back()`, that you asked about, is pretty easy to fix. But your real problem here, that you need to address, is how you need to design your `end()` iterator value, and what should it be. What you have now is not going to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I added the --operator and changed back to *--end(). I understand why m_back+1 is not working for me. But I'm still confused about how to get end to work.

Comment: The way to get end() to work is to figure out how to make it meet all the requirements that an ending iterator value must meet. One common way, but not the only way, is to always have a dummy node placed at the end of the list, so an empty list contains just the dummy node. A pointer to that dummy node is your end() iterator, and all real nodes in the list are inserted before it. Or, have end() represented by a null pointer, but then the iterator must also contain a pointer to its own list, so that operator-- can work properly. There are many ways to do it.